# Does a "fact" have to be true?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I'm struggling to decide whether to jettison use of the word *fact*, because the definition appears to be not solid enough to support continued usage. What do I mean by that? Look at one "meaning ladder" (taken from Random House via [TFD Online](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fact)) among several on the same page:

> **fact**
>
> 1. something that actually exists: *Your fears have no basis in fact.*
> 2. something known to exist or to have happened.
> 3. a truth known by actual experience or observation; something known to be true.
> 4. something said to be true or supposed to have happened.
> 5. an actual or alleged event or circumstance, **as distinguished from its legal effect or consequence**.

This definition marches us from something that exists to something that is merely *supposed* to be true to something that may be "actual or alleged." (And yes, I am aware that dictionaries don't dictate the meanings of words; they record meanings from usages. And the meanings of this word *as it is used and recorded in English* seem to be antagonistic toward each other.)

What are we to do with all this? Does a fact require the modifier *true* to be judged genuine? When we preface a statement with "in fact" don't we mean *What follows is the truth*? The aforementioned dictionary certainly thinks so:

> **in fact**, **in truth**; really; indeed: *They are, in fact, great patriots*.

Here *fact* and *truth* are equated absolutely. So I'm wondering: how do we distinguish between what is a fact in the sense of absolute truth and what is a fact of a lesser order? Other words can have many shades of meaning, but this one seems somehow like it shouldn't. So if I hear the word *fact* without hearing *true* before it, does it even deserve the term?

**A cautionary note**

I'm not really looking for a discussion of *truth* in the philosophical sense. The scope of this question is limited to the meaning of a word in English, not the meaning of an absolute concept as rational beings can or should understand it. What I'm really after, as I mentioned in a comment, is whether the adulteration of this particular word renders it, ultimately, meaningless, and therefore something to be avoided.

In conclusion, I offer this quote from Howard K. Zinn, from his Afterword to *A People's History of the United States*:

> But there is no such thing as a pure fact, innocent of interpretation. Behind
> every fact presented to the world—by a teacher, a writer, anyone—is a
> judgment. The judgment that has been made is that this fact is important, and
> that other facts, omitted, are not important

Comment: A fact must be true, but then, what is truth??  (You're asking a question that philosophers have puzzled over for millennia.)

Comment: @HotLicks: I think I brought it down from the teleological empyrean enough that it could be answered in this forum.

Comment: Yet you ask "how do we distinguish between what is a fact in the sense of absolute truth and what is a fact of a lesser order?"

Comment: Only in terms of English. Other languages may have different words to distinguish the two meanings. Apparently we do not. Our word is unfortunately overloaded.

Comment: This link may shed some  light on the issue:http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/what-is-the-difference-between-fact-and-truth

Comment: @Josh61: Thanks. Interesting comment, but in the end it really only leaves me in the same pickle.

Comment: Are you looking for indisputable evidence that *fact and truth* are unmistakable synonyms, or viceversa?

Comment: @Josh61: More of a usage question, really. I'm wondering if the adulteration of the word I describe renders it, ultimately, meaningless and therefore something to be avoided.

Comment: -1 for use of the phrase "the definition".  We have the word as it is used, and attempts to define that *usage*. Usage in the wild can be sloppier than the OP would like, but that doesn't mean that the definitions are themselves sloppy. The lexicographers are not "marching us". They're watching us march.

Comment: @TimRomano: In no wise do I suggest that dictionaries rule the world. The various definitions exist and have been recorded as I describe. Cannot I use the term definition without any order of operation or appeal to authority concerning it?

Comment: @Robusto - That's the interesting thing about "facts" -- people get to choose their own.  This is what makes the word often useless.

Comment: @Robusto can you give an example of the 'non-truth' version of 'fact'? I'm having a hard time seeing a problem here without actual usage where fact is not a true thing.

Comment: @Mitch: "something said to be true or supposed to have happened" is not something that actually is true or did happen.

Comment: @Robusto: Your dilemma can be restated: *Can I use a word precisely if other people use it loosely?* Definitions found in dictionaries simply *describe* the word as it is used in various contexts. Any *prescriptive* authority boils down to "people don't use the word that way in that context".  Context is king, also in lexicography.

Comment: @TimRomano: You're reacting to a burr under your saddle that doesn't really exist. And people *do* use the term *fact* to mean "information" without reference to whether the information is accurate or not. If a fact is always true, then why do people ask all of the following: "What are the facts?" and "Are those the real facts?" and "Are those true facts?"

Comment: 'a true fact' is a pleonasm, yes. But 'in fact' is an idiom meaning 'it has been established'. Also, people may use 'in fact' wishfully. I don't think this is like 'literally'.

Comment: So is your point then that 'fact' is slipping in its meaning like 'literally'?

Comment: @Mitch: Something like that. It is certainly not pristine, if it ever was.

Comment: The fact is that lies have been shopped as truth so often for so long that _fact_ has taken on an aura of "official reality" in many contexts, to avoid appearing to contradict widely-held counterfactual presuppositions (like "The Earth is flat, is about 6000 years old, and is not changing its climate"). So you have to be careful when somebody uses the word in certain contexts. However, this is hardly a new phenomenon.

Comment: I don't grasp your beef with "supposed to have happened".  The Grand Canyon is supposed to have been formed by erosion, though no one was there to witness the process.

Comment: @dennisdeems: Do you see no difference between "supposed to have happened" and "happened"?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do.

Comment: What resources can we provide? What evidence do you require. It is, I suspect, one of those interesting, but subjective, questions which cannot have a "right" answer. Ultimately you, the OP, will choose the answer which you "agree" with most, and not the most objective one (ironically an answer containing hard cold facts). If this had been asked by anyone else, it would have been immediately closed as POB.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: *All* answers on this site are judged based on the polling mechanism you cite and subject to the same limitations. Many are probably as subjective as this one, if not even more so. Is it wrong to look for consensus here?

Comment: for those who are interested in semantics and etymology, be sure to check out `axiom`, `perception`, and `verity`. (Perception becomes fact/truth when everyone "perceives" it to be true.)

Comment: Here is some context from my past, and I can't be the only one that learned this... When I was in elementary school, we had assignments to tell if a sentence was a "fact" or an "opinion".  Facts did not have to be true, but they had to be measurable or observable.  For instance, "That is a cool car" is an opinion.  "That is a fast car" is a fact.  "The sky is green" would also be a fact, even though it happens to be false.  The color of the sky is measurable.  Some students would get tripped up and call an opinion a fact if they agreed with it and vice-verse.

Comment: It is a fact that we cannot travel in time, but is it a fact that time travel is impossible? Somebody from the general public might well state the latter as a  scientific fact, but it doesn't mean the statement is true or accurate. People use and abuse words every day, I don't see what's particularly special about *fact*. If the writer knows his/her stuff and has data to backup their statement, then why not use the term *fact*?

Comment: Suppose we knew beyond a shadow of a doubt that A were true.  We think A is true, and, in fact, we consider it a fact.  Perhaps we would then need to invent a new term to indicate "absolute truth," except that the idea of absolute truth is fleeting.  Nobody knows absolute truth.  It's a myth.  We technically can't even [prove number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems), which we ourselves invented.  We can't even prove that what we see isn't being simulated or even that we exist.  Absolute truth does not exist.

Comment: If this is, as the site would suggest, a question about English, and not philosophy, then the answer can be found here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-incorrect-facts-an-oxymoron

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: Haha, busted. I'm getting old, I didn't remember answering that lo these many years ago.

Comment: Now I need to determine if I'm making a substantially different point. Hmm . . .

Comment: @Robusto If we're talking about English, and not some fluffy philosophical discussion about "truth", then the answer is already there: A "fact", by definition, is "indisputable" :)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: OK, I'm nearly inclined to agree with you, but work with me for a second. Do four intervening years of irritation at the world not agreeing with that definition count for anything? (As witnessed by further dictionary citations that blur the line?)

Comment: @Robusto I'm not convinced by lesser dictionaries myself, I often find mistakes in them :) That said, I think it's fair to state that, the word "fact" is used to distinguish between things that are indisputable and things that are debatable.

Comment: Tru dat. OK, you convinced me.

Comment: If you're saying that 'fact' has slipped in usage to mean something metaphorical like 'factoid' (in analogy with 'literal' slipping in meaning to mean something like 'really a lot', then I've come to accept that that is possible, but I don't see that it is happening. I see it is more that people believe they're using it about facts, but are actually not (the Great Wall example). I realize that this is not terribly different from the situation with 'literally' but I don't have enough examples of the faulty usage that you see. Can you give more?

Comment: My answer got eaten by the close-fairy right as I submitted it, and now it's gone T_T the duplicate has an incorrect answer (ironic, given the subject matter) highest-voted and accepted.  *le sigh*

Comment: @Mari-LouA: This has got to be a first in SE history: an asker's question marked as duplicate of a question where _they_ gave the accpted answer!

Comment: @TusharRaj: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21911908#21911908 (I voted to close this myself once I was made aware of the contretemps).

Comment: @Robusto: Also unusual in SE history: The OP not commenting _at all_ on the leading answer in a popular post. May I ask what you thought of my answer?

Comment: @TusharRaj: I planned to comment once the dust had settled on these. Your answer is definitely useful, and I'm still considering accepting it. In my own mind I'm really struggling with this, however; I used to be more certain about the issue myself (at least I was four years ago) but now I'm not so sure. I like that this question provoked a lot of ragged, untidy conflict about the matter. I was also waiting to give out up votes, but I suppose now's as good a time as any. You just got one from me.

Comment: @Robusto: Thanks. If there are any points about my answer you'd like me to clarify, I'd love to. It isn't airtight, admittedly, but I think I've been able to get my point across. The takeaway should be the realtionship between the utterance of the word `fact` and the time it's uttered.

Comment: @TusharRaj I'm still waiting on an answer... :)

Comment: @TusharRaj By all means, flag away! I'm not attacking you at all. I'm sincerely trying to understand your POV, which, actually if you think about it, is this: *A fact does not have to be true*, but if you're refusing to discuss this further, so be it. Personally, what I subscribe to is surmised very well here: http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fact

Comment: Guys, let's keep it sweet, OK? No sense getting in a flame war at this point. :)

Comment: See what I mean about widely-held presuppositions?

Comment: A "true fact" has to be true. True facts can however be contrasted with the modern phenomenon of "alternative facts".

Comment: @hippietrail: Agreed.

Comment: @hippietrail A "true fact" is a tautology. The use of the phrase "alternative facts", along with the lies that were used alongside them by Conway led to law professors filing a legal complaint against her (a practising lawyer). https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/law-professors-file-misconduct-complaint-against-kellyanne-conway/2017/02/23/442b02c8-f9e3-11e6-bf01-d47f8cf9b643_story.html

Comment: This already has an answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-incorrect-facts-a-contradiction-in-terms

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: Yeah, no. That is my accepted answer you link to, but I reconsidered my position based on the way the world had moved into the realm of "alternative facts" and the like.

Comment: @Django: A position is not necessarily based on "personal feelings." But if you really want to get this question closed as a duplicate you'll have to put in your own work on that. Good luck.

Comment: @Robusto I've now addressed the myriads of mistakes in the accepted answer in my answer. Perhaps it will convince you that your original position was the correct one :)

Comment: @Robusto Maybe the older question can be closed to point to this more definitive one?

Comment: Mr. Gandhi said, "God is truth, and truth is God". No philosopher has raised 'fact' to this level.  Here lies the difference. Fact is relative (which people say, half-facts, true facts, less true facts, etc.), whereas, Truth is something comparable to God.

Comment: Doesn't three-quarters of a million Google hits for "the facts are in dispute" give a definitive answer?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Well, "teh" gets a quarter of a million Google hits as well. I don't know what that teaches us.

Comment: @Robusto (1) "The facts are in dispute" is not an unknown expression. OP and/or you can of course check to see if a reasonable proportion of them are probably actually _not_ the work of the random acts of chimpanzees at typewriters. (2) If there are a reasonable number of distinct and ungarbled examples, I'd say we have a clear 'no'. Of course, OP (oh, it's you) should be aware of polysemy, hypernymy, and precising/stipulative definitions. 'Fact' needs to be defined before use in any situation where confusion / duplicity might occur. Then there are scare-quote _facts_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: (1) The number of Google hits a thing gets is indicative of nothing. (2) Even NGram results, which [I view with much skepticism](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/should-we-allow-google-ngrams-to-be-presented-as-statistical-evidence-without-qu), are more useful. (3) You should be aware that many of "hits" that come up in a Google search lead to the same ultimate source. (4) I'm somewhat in agreement with you nevertheless; if you can bother to put your thoughts into an answer I'll likely upvote it, and if it's really persuasive I'll give you the checkmark.

Comment: I'd just reinforce your 'the meanings of this word as it is used and recorded in English seem to be antagonistic toward each other', changing to 'various senses of this word as it is used and recorded in English are quite obviously antagonistic toward each other.' [No great surprise there; someone came up with 'all words are infinitely polysemous'.] Perhaps more than with most words, this could cause real problems when using 'fact'. For this reason, outside childrens encyclopedias say [and I'm not too sure about that, either], the term must be qualified. 'Something I think is right?' ...

Comment: 'Something I "know" is right?' Something stated in OED? CGEL? Wikipedia? By Brian Cox? Something sworn to by a witness in court? _Something on the front page of the Daily ...'? _**Something politician X has said**_ ? I try to use modals (from 'according to X' to 'what we think is' to the occasional weaselly 'allegedly'). But I think an answer to 'what to do?' is far too opinion-based, too situation-dependent to address in an 'answer' here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you misunderstand. "The facts are in dispute" means that the facts haven't been established, not that there are several conflicting facts. See: https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/ld199899/ldjudgmt/jd991028/rey06.htm "If the facts are in dispute, the jury is called upon to consider the evidence and pass upon the issues thus raised."

Comment: @Django Reinhardt I think you misunderstand. ' "The facts are in dispute" means that the facts haven't been established, not that there are several conflicting facts' assumes definition 1, 2 or 3 from Random House. If we take 5b, 'an alleged event or circumstance', people could be arguing over whether the alleged event ('fact') actually happened. It might not have (ie not been a 'fact, definition 1'). This is what the question is all about.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's relating to legal terms, eg. "question of fact". See: https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/fact

Comment: @Django Reinhardt Do you disagree that M-W's '_fact_ can have the meaning _an alleged event or circumstance_' is allowable? If so, please contact them. I see in your answer you only select those dictionaries not disagreeing with your viewspoint. The 'ever-reliable'(?) OED and AHD are not among them; they're quoted in other answers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Again, you are referring to the word in relation to the legal term "question of fact" or "finding of fact", as stated clearly by Merriam Webster. If you're going to deliberately distort the truth to support your claim, then your claim cannot be very strong.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt : From a court case held as an example by the [Stanford Law School](https://scocal.stanford.edu/opinion/estate-smith-26065): 'The majority opinion is essentially based on the statement that "The facts are not in dispute." But according to the record as I view it the facts are in dispute.' [J Schauer]. So the majority say A, B, C ... are 'facts'. But Schauer disagrees on at least one point. We can't be absolutely sure that what  'the majority' have labelled 'facts' are actually facts in the incontrovertibly true sense.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As I already said, that means that the facts haven't been established and so are open to dispute, not that there are several conflicting facts. I really hope you didn't spend much time digging out that court transcript thinking it meant something notable :-/

Comment: It's a fact that the dictionary cited here includes the definition 4b '_fact_: something supposed to have happened'. Of course, some don't accept dictionary definitions. They may well stop at definition 3 here say.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A fact does, in fact, have to be the truth at the time you're using the word.

By 'truth', I mean something you *believe* to be true (due to any of several possible reasons).¹

Consider: "The number of planets in the solar system is eight."
A few years ago, this was not a fact. It *is* now. (Just an example, don't attack the example.)

[**EDIT:** Before 1917, people thought it to be a *fact* that the atom was the smallest particle of matter. Today, it is a *fact* that it isn't, and we were wrong in thinking it was... I'm including this example to show that in light of the new fact, what we *thought* was a fact previously, can be rendered untrue for that time too; something @Jay pointed out my previous example didn't specify]

When a jury convicts a man, it's a fact that he's guilty. If he's later acquitted, it's a fact that he is 'not guilty'. (As far as the public is concerned. Individuals who actually saw the crime might know, *for a fact*, whether it's true or not)

What I'm trying to say is that the word `fact` is used for what you know (or sincerely believe) to be the truth or what is widely believed to be the truth at the time of speaking. Facts are subject to change.

Something is *not* a fact if you know/believe it to be untrue or if it can be easily be shown to *not* be widely believed at the time.

The two can contradict. That's when *myth* comes into play.

> Tom: "Interesting fact: you can see the Great Wall of China from space." (Widely believed).
>
> Neil: "As a matter of *fact*, you can't. That's a myth." (I went to space. I know better.)

---

¹ <sub>Please note that I'm talking exclusively about the cases where you use the word `fact`. In those cases, I infer you strongly believe it to be true.</sub>

Comment: Robusto: Tom's usage in "Interesting fact" is not a slippage of meaning of 'fact', it is just _wrong_. Just as if you point at a dog and say 'cat'. You may mean 'cat' sincerely or have bad eyesight or have had an aneurysm, but either way it is a mistake.

Comment: The phrase "a fact in law" is not uncommon, IME, and reflects the idea that the legal meaning of guilt and innocence is not, in fact, definitive and a legal fact may really be a fiction (a "technicality") or even nonsense ('"for the law supposes that your wife acts under your direction." "If the law supposes that," said Mr. Bumble, squeezing his hat emphatically in both hands, "the law is a ass..."' — Dickens, Oliver Twist)

Comment: I (a lawyer) have never heard the phrase "a fact in law" in legal practice. Fictions are not facts, nor are presumptions. They are things treated as true even if either they aren't or are not known to be. I doubt whether there was ever a presumption that a wife acted under husband's direction *so as to assign the wife's criminal actions to the husband*. I don't think that is how couverture worked.

Comment: just to clarify, i'm pretty sure the common myth is that you can see the great wall from *space* not the *moon*. both are untrue, of course.

Comment: @sgroves: You're right. But the example works better with moon. And Neil. Neil Armstrong did actually go on the record debunking this myth.

Comment: Just going to ignore you and attack the example. It was a fact that the solar system had 9 planets before. It is currently a fact that the solar system has 8 planets now. Our changing definition of 'planet' does not relegate the veracity of facts that were true. This is the same as saying "my shirt is red" as a fact. Tomorrow, it will no longer be a fact, but it will always have been a fact that I was wearing a red shirt today. It's not like we suddenly found an extra planet that we hadn't known about.

Comment: @Scott: well, that's not much of an attack, since you seem to have inferred something I wasn't claiming. Earlier, the solar system had 9 planets: fact. Therefore, it had 8 planets:  not a fact. That's what I said. You are essentially making the same pint I was trying to make. Facts are subject to change. And using the word relates to what's true at the time of speaking.

Comment: @Scott: And one more thing. It doesn't matter _why_ the number of planets changed. If a planet gets blown up, or a new one is discovered, or we change the definition of solar system, or planet, or nine; it would be equally incorrect to call the old information a fact now.

Comment: Hmm, I have to disagree. I don't think this is at all the common understanding of the word "fact". If I said, "It is a fact of history that Columbus was the first European to reach America", I can't imagine someone saying, "No, that's not true. It's not a fact, because Columbus thought he was in India." Or to take your own example, if a person was convicted of a crime, and later there was overwhelming evidence that he was innocent, someone might very well say, "As it turns out, the fact is that he was innocent all along."

Comment: @Jay: March 3, he was convicted. March 10, he was absolved. It _is_ a fact on March 11th, that he was innocent all along; but it's **not** a fact on the 5th. (I'm talking about the general public.)

Comment: @Jay: You are ignoring what I said in my first sentence. Usage of `fact` is related to the time it's being used. If someone said that about Columbus today, he would be using `fact` correctly according to my answer. I don't know what led you to believe otherwise.

Comment: @TusharRaj I understood you to be saying that something could have been a fact yesterday but not be a fact today. That is very different from saying that people THOUGHT it was a fact yesterday but today we know that it is not. If you meant the latter, well, that's not what you said. Maybe unclear wording.

Comment: @Jay: I see, well all the examples I thought of then, (heliocentrism etc) were so old I wasn't sure what shape English and the word _fact_ were in back then. So I went with the planet one, which had a weakness, as you pointed out. Edited to include another example. Please see.

Comment: @Mitch: Tom's usage isn't wrong if he believes the statement to be true.

Comment: @reinierpost  I am agreeing with you that Tom's _usage_ isn't wrong (he is using the word 'fact' correctly for his beliefs), but that he is objectively wrong (the statement "  'The Great Wall can be seen from space' is a fact" does not accord with ... the real world (other people's beliefs supported by objective data). I'd also say Tom is not using the word wrong, even if he is lying or bullshitting; he's trying to get across the idea that a statement is true (whether he believes it or it is or anything).

Comment: @Mitch: yes: we agree that the 'fact' he stated isn't a fact - but as you can see, not all commenters reserve the use of the term 'fact' in that way.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: A fact is something you believe to be true. That does NOT imply that everything you believe to be true is a fact. And before 1917, "all possible knowledge" backed up an atom not being splittable. Just like today "all possible knowledge" back up countless scientific _facts_ which are bound to be revised in the future.

Comment: @TusharRaj Perhaps it's your wording then, but it's categorically incorrect to state: "A fact is something you believe to be true." That is NOT the definition of a fact. A fact is something that can be demonstrably shown to be true -- even if it can later demonstrably shown to be wrong due to better instruments.

Comment: @TusharRaj Also, I think part of your confusion stems from the idea that people before 1917 make a mistake with regards to the atom. They did not. They took measurements, and those measurements who still be true today. For some reason you've attributed a widely held belief and described it as "fact". Anyone who stated, prior to 1917, that it's a fact that the atom could not be split, would have been wrong then, too -- even in their own time, before we knew it was possible. It might have been a belief, but nobody could have stated it was a fact.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: I think we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @TusharRaj Please explain to me why it is a not a fact that there's a higher power if someone states: "I believe there is a higher power". According to your definition, it is a fact.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: I won't be dragged into a flamewar. This isn't about metaphysics anyway. All I can say is: it _is_ a fact **for you**. Not necessarily for everyone else. There are people who swear UFOs/ghosts/Loch Ness monsters exist because they _believe_ they saw one. They consider it a fact. Others aren't bound to. As a better example, consider a person ABC who watches XYZ kill someone and the jury acquits him. For the public, _fact_ is that XYZ is not guilty. For ABC, _fact_ is that XYZ is definitely guilty. You say facts are universal; I say they're not.

Comment: @TusharRaj It's not a flame war. I'd just like to you explain to me how, by your definition, it's a fact that there's a higher power if someone states, "I believe there is a higher power". (And, as per your other examples; I'll ignore the UFO one, as it's clearly flawed, but re: the person found guilty: It's a fact that they were found guilty, but that does not, in any way, mean it's a fact that they commited the crime -- plenty of people have been found guilty of crimes they did not commit. The *facts* never changed, no matter what the jury decides.)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: I must say that neither of us is likely to change their mind. This discussion is futile. And anything religious has the makings of a flamewar. You asked for an explanation which I provided. You are ignoring it. By your logic, you can never really tell what the facts are since neither you nor anyone else knows it for every John Doe ever sentenced. What you're describing is something else.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: And PLEASE STOP EDITING MY POST to include your version in it.

Comment: @TusharRaj Your example does not make sense to me, which is why I'm asking for a simple clarification. (My example is not about anyone's specific religion at all. That's why I used "higher power".) Also, I  have edited your post twice: First to impose to my understanding -- rejected. Second to fix tenses and a minor edit to clarify *your* argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24273/discussion-between-tushar-raj-and-django-reinhardt).

Comment: I've now addressed all of the many valid comments and criticisms of this answer, and added them into my answer - with some real world examples to back them up: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/249350/603

Comment: "When a jury convicts a man, it's a fact that he's guilty." The takes that as a fact, but it is not a fact.  "If he's later acquitted, it's a fact that he is 'not guilty'." Even the law does not take that as a fact.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt suppose someone is convicted of burglary because the jury (or judge, in some cases, acting as a finder of fact) determines that the defendant broke a window to gain access to a house.  Legally, then, that the defendant broke the window is a fact _even if it isn't true._  As far as the court is concerned, it's true, but subsequent evidence might arise proving that it isn't true (for example, DNA analysis showing that the blood belonged to someone else and other evidence that the defendant was actually 500 miles away at the time).  That is an example of an untrue fact.

Comment: @phoog No. You can say, "it's a fact that the person was *found* guilty in a court of law". That's how it's always reported and talked about. Nobody would say "it's a fact that this person is guilty" (or "innocent") due to the result of a trial. Everyone knows there are wrongful convictions. It's simply a fact that the evidence convinced the jurors of the person's guilt. It's not a "fact" that OJ Simpson is innocent, for example.

Comment: @phoog Re: A court of law. The "findings of fact" would be: A window was broken. Genetic evidence belonging to the accused was found at the scene. These are the facts. The court/jurors takes the facts and try to determine the most likely explanation.

Comment: In school, I learned that a fact was something that is an objective piece of information, regardless of whether it is true or not. For example, saying Tushar Raj is the president is a fact since it is an objective piece of information that stays false no matter how you feel. It is not an opinion, so it is a fact. What do you think?

Answer (score 14):

There are some good answers here. I thought it would be useful to expand on meaning (5) in your list, in case you ever have to deal with it.

In English common law, most matters (criminal or civil) came to be tried by a jury. Over time a rule developed that some questions would be decided by the jury and others by the judge. The jury decided questions of fact whereas the judge decided questions of law.

For example, in the English law of theft, one element of the crime that must be established by the prosecution is that the defendant acted "dishonestly". The meaning of "dishonest" is a question of law, but whether the defendant was dishonest according to that definition is a question of fact.

There are practical consequences of this distinction. In English criminal procedure, you may appeal the judge's decision on questions of law, but not the jury's decision on questions of fact.

In this usage "fact" is used in a slightly technical sense in opposition to the word "law" but it is essentially intended to be restricted to statements that are true, at least that is the hope.

Comment: +1 Thanks for that clarification on meaning 5, I knew it had to me something like that. And apologies for the cheap shot in my answer...it just seemed to fit the argument I was making too well.

Comment: @JeffSahol - no worries. I both practice and teach law and I am very well used to the cheap shots.

Comment: Just want to add that this is in fact the historical definition of the word, all the way up to the 16th century or so, and hence its persistence in the English legal system.

Comment: The word "alleged" used in the dictionary should also be seen in a legal context, e.g. "al-legation", to support a plea/legal claim, and under law, of course, all allegations need to be scrutinized. This is different from the common use in which use of the qualifier "alleged" is often inherently mixed with a heavy dose of skepticism.

Answer (score 8):

Your question sounds as if you are in a Quixotic fight against a particular false Scotsman, not realising that [there is no such thing as a true Scotsman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman), or for that matter, a true X for any word *X* whatsoever.

You could just as well be "struggling to decide whether to jettison use of the word *word*, because the definition appears to be not solid enough to support continued usage". There is no clear boundary between what is a word and what isn't. Is "ouch" a word? Or "hmmm"? How about "Aargh"? "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaargh"? Is "blasé" an English word? What about "révisioniste"? Is "Agatha"? And "Christie"? Is the symbol used by 'the artist formerly known as Prince' a word? Is "a priori" an English word? Or is it two? How about the two constituents? Note also that in languages which do not separate words by spaces, it can be practically impossible to distinguish separate little function words from suffixes or prefixes.

Who is this *I* who is struggling anyway? Do you mean your body, your mind (whatever that is) or your soul (whatever that is)? Did this *I* already exist when 'you' were born and possessed only a tiny percentage of the atoms that you would now consider your own, whereas many of the atoms 'you' possessed then have found something else to do in the meantime? Did it already exist before you could think clearly and create memories that you can still draw on?

What do you mean by *struggle to decide*? Who is this ominous person trying to prevent you from deciding, the one you apparently have to struggle against?

What do you mean by *the definition*? Since when do words have unique, well defined definitions? Where would you be able to find the one true definition of a word? How would you be able to understand it without using similar definitions for all the words used in it, leading to loops and an infinite regress?

Facts are true because (in some sense that I don't wish to make precise) the meaning cloud for the word *fact* is mostly a subset of the meaning cloud for the word *true*. Although *false facts* are mostly outside the one for *true*, while still in the periphery of the one for *fact*.

For similar reasons, birds can fly even though some birds have broken wings or happen to be penguins. And facts are true even though some are not.

Comment: Nicely put: "For similar reasons, birds can fly even though some birds have broken wings or happen to be penguins. And facts are true even though some are not."

Comment: This answer... is beautiful.

Comment: Except the poster said he was NOT asking for a philosophical discussion on the nature of truth, but simply a clarification on the definition of the word "fact".

Comment: @Jay: True enough, yet I enjoyed this answer so much that I voted it up. :)

Comment: @Hans: The person I'm struggling with to decide is, of course, myself.

Answer (score 7):

> Does a “fact” have to be true?

No.

---

Here is a detailed definition of *fact* from *OED* for the sense that we are dealing with:

> A thing that has really occurred or is actually the case; a thing certainly known to be a real occurrence or to represent the truth. Hence: a particular truth known by actual observation or authentic testimony, as opposed to an inference, a conjecture, or a fiction; a datum of experience, as distinguished from the conclusions that may be based on it.

But it is also mentioned that:

> Where the truth of a matter is disputed or in doubt, this sense overlaps with sense "A piece of information allegedly or conceivably true; something presented as a fact  but which is disputed or unproven; (more strongly) an unproved assertion, an allegation."

In fact, the truth is, it depends.

You understand that the fact is not a truth from the context. Usually, the negative words like *false, unproven, disputed* etc. reveal that. (They might modify *fact* also.)

Some examples from *OED*:

> - This is..**a false fact**, supported by a supposed motive - *1824, Westm. Rev.*
> - It bases its accusations on false statements and **inaccurate facts**. - *1941,   A. M. Lindbergh Diary*
> - Waksal hotly **disputed some of the facts** in that story. - *2002,   Vanity Fair*

<sub>Note: Of course it can be discussed or interpreted further but I focused on the usage of the word.</sub>

Comment: Another example occurs in the expression "You've got your facts wrong," which, as I understand it, means "The instances or data points you are putting forward or are basing your argument on are not valid." The interesting thing (to me) about this expression is that it doesn't say, as it could have, "Your facts aren't facts [that is, _factual_]." Instead, it emphasizes that the instances or data points are not valid, even while conceding that they may still be called "facts."

Comment: @SvenYargs: Good catch. I prefer saying "Those aren't the facts" myself.

Comment: To me the caveat reads the same as if, considering the meaning of the word "horse", the dictionary said, "where the species of a creature is disputed or in doubt, this sense overlaps with the sense, "a creature allegedly or conceivably a horse: something presented as a horse but which is disputed or unproven"". Normally I wouldn't say "your facts aren't true, and I'll prove it", and I wouldn't say "your horse is a cow, and I'll prove it". But you certainly can, in both cases using "X" to mean "so-called X" or "alleged X". Am I missing a subtlety that applies to facts but not horses?

Comment: ... or is this just a particularly noteworthy case of the general phenomenon for any word, that it can be used provisionally when the truth is in doubt?

Comment: "Where the truth of a matter is disputed or in doubt", I believe you're confusing this in relation to the legal term "question of fact". I don't have a copy of OED to confirm this, but I would guess that's the case.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you are reading too much into the last two definitions listed. The fifth one is apparently a legal term of art and as we all know lawyers have little use for the actual truth. The fourth covers instances where facts are asserted without being verified. If I asked a group of toddlers for a list of facts about where babies come from, that's still a list of facts.

Finally, the same argument can be made for truth, "a fact or belief that is accepted as true" being one of its meanings. So now we're trespassing into the realm of epistemology.stackexchange.com.

Comment: 'Instances where facts (let's say sense 1) are asserted as such without being verified' are extremely common (have a look at a few answers here). If RH labels 'statements asserted as facts' as 'facts', then this forms the hub of the question. It cannot reasonably just be dismissed.

Answer (score 4):

*"What I'm really after... is whether the adulteration of this particular word renders it...meaningless, and therefore something to be avoided."*

The word is not being "adulterated"; it is being used in different ways *in different speech contexts*.

A fact is that which exists or existed, happens or happened, and which can, as a result, be *known, thought, supposed, believed, stated, averred, alleged, etc".

These ancillary definitions involving speech contexts are not really definitions of "fact" *per se* but of the kinds of mental attitudes we can express, or the kinds of predications we can make, in respect to ontological fact. The lexicographers have made a leap from ontology to (everyday) epistemology.

Comment: You say the word "is being used in different ways in different speech contexts." That's fine for most words, but that's part of what I'm trying to establish. When is it OK for a "fact" not to be true?

Comment: An ontological fact exists; it is neither true nor false.  "True" is an attribute of *predication*. A statement is "a statement of fact" (i.e. true) when it comports with the ontological fact(s) it's about. A statement that does not comport with the ontological fact(s) is a falsehood. When someone knowingly calls a falsehood a "fact" (by which they mean "a statement of fact"), they're said to be lying.

Comment: @TimRomano: Beautifully put. May I suggest editing that into your answer. +1.

Answer (score 2):

From [Hard Facts](http://www.differencebetween.net/miscellaneous/difference-between-fact-and-truth/): nuances in meaning and usage exist, but there are good reasons to use both terms:

> - What is the clear difference between a fact and a truth? Well, if you look into most dictionaries, you will be amazed to find that the two words are actually very close in terms of their definitions. This is because the two terms are very much related. That’s why you really can’t blame people for recognizing both as similar terms.
> - ***Fact is basically something that exists, or is present in reality***. Hence, these are things that can be seen visually, and these are the things that can actually be verified. Facts are objective matters rather than subjective ones. It is not just something that you believe, but rather these are more or less the things that can be observed empirically, or by the senses. So, facts can be seen and heard, as well as proven by the other senses.
> - ***Truth can be described as the true state of a certain matter, may it be a person, a place, a thing or an event. It is what a person has come to believe***. If he believes that something is true, then it is true. It also answers the questions of what’s really happening. In the technical sense, facts can answer certain ‘why’ questions, like ‘where’ or ‘when’, and even ‘how’, while truth answers the question ‘why’. The question of ‘how’, and even ‘what’, are said to be answerable by either of the two.
> - ***In terms of permanence, a fact happens to be more permanent, and almost always seems to have no changes. It is more constant than truths***. For example, when you say that the sun will always rise from the east and set in the west, you are telling a fact, but when you say that you are in Los Angeles, then that is a truth, at least for that exact moment. Several hours from that time you may have gone somewhere else, making your previous statement a fallacy. Thus, a truth is something that is not universal, it is more subjective, and depends on the current situation. That’s why the truth’s existence is said to be more temporary than that of facts.
>
>   1. Facts are more objective when compared to the more subjective truths.
>   2. Facts are more permanent when compared to the more temporary truths.
>   3. Facts exist in reality, whereas truths are usually the things that one believes to be true, or the things that are true in the current situation.
>   4. Facts can also answer the ‘where,’ ‘when’ and ‘how’ questions, whereas truths answer the ‘why’ question.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two types of facts: [Universals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_(metaphysics)), which are universally true and is usually part of common sense about how the physical world works, and Facts that are statements you believe are true, but not necessarily.

In your precise case, about the usage of the word "fact" for communication purpose, we must also account for the incompleteness and incertainty of the interlocuter: he/she may be using a prejudice that is just false, or be lying, or just misestimating his/her level of confidence in the statement he/she made.

So, in the end, a **fact can only be what one believe is true, as opposed to what is true universally**.

BTW, this is a very important topic of research in [knowledge representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_representation_and_reasoning), [logics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modal_logic), [artificial intelligence](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Bernard_Moulin/publication/220637771_A_taxonomy_of_argumentation_models_used_for_knowledge_representation/links/09e41509bfad182563000000.pdf) and in any epistemological system (ie, systems that represent knowledge) in general.

Comment: ontology is being, epistemology is knowing.

Comment: Your argument sounds like we can't REALLY know anything. I agree, technically.

Comment: See, here we have one particular metaphysical system being asserted: the medieval view that truth is about universals, while facts are contingient statements about Aristotelian accidental properties. And the person making it isn't aware that this is an entirely different conception of truth and fact than a modern scientist would make, using a metaphysics which denies the existence of universals; or that a post-modernist would make, defining "facts" as social conventions; or that a pragmatist would make, defining "truth" as a praxis which proves useful.

Comment: @Zebrafish Are you sure?

Answer (score 2):

When I refer to something as a fact, without qualifications, I am implying that it is true. This situation is not much different than when I say something like "I ate a grapefruit for breakfast." I am implying that I actually did. I might be lying, but the meaning of my sentence is that my eating of a grapefruit is the truth. I can refer to an event as alleged, no longer implying it is necessarily true: "Allegedly, he ate a grapefruit for breakfast." Similarly, I can use the word *fact* to refer to that event, whether true or not: "The alleged fact of your eating a grapefruit is immaterial to the question at hand." It is possible to drop the word *alleged* in this last sentence, and without it, the sentence will be ambiguous about whether I am implying that you did eat a grapefruit. Some people will interpret it to mean I implied you did, others will interpret it to mean I am agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

As the definitions you quote indicate, the word "fact" is used in two different senses. It can mean something that is true, or it can mean something that is claimed to be true, but which may or may not actually be true.

On the one hand, people will say things like, "It is a fact that Senator Jones accepted a bribe." Meaning, this statement is true. Or conversely, "No, that's not a fact at all." Meaning, that statement is false.

On the other hand, people also commonly say things like, "The facts are in dispute", meaning, we are arguing about what is true and what is not. Editors talk about "fact-checking" a document to determine whether the facts it states are true or not. We talk about "unproven facts" or "questionable facts". We say, "You have your facts wrong." Etc. If the word "fact" was understood to mean "statements that are true", then it would be a paradox to say "unproven facts" or "disputed facts" or "the facts are wrong". How can something that we all know is true be in dispute, etc?

Comment: A statement can be both true and unproven or disputed.

Comment: @Acccumulation True. But if it's unproven or disputed, than by definition we don't know whether it's true or not. If the word "fact" means that something is true, than to refer to a statement as a "disputed fact" would be somewhere between a contradiction -- is it disputed or is it a fact? -- and an assertion that it is true but some people continue to deny it.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not really looking for a discussion of truth in the philosophical sense. The scope of this question is limited to the meaning of a word in English, not the meaning of an absolute concept as rational beings can or should understand it.

[I've rewritten this in response to comments.]
I'm afraid you *are* looking for a discussion of truth in the philosophical sense.  Nearly everyone agrees that facts are necessarily true; they disagree on what "true" and "necessary" mean.  They also disagree over the law of the excluded middle, which says that every claim is either true or false.

(A) Philosophers, Christians, Hegelians (including Marxists, Progressives, and Nazis), humanities professors, and post-modernists believe that "true" means "logically proven to be absolutely, universally, eternally true".  This has been the standard philosophical definition of "truth" since Plato.  I'll use "True" (capital T) to denote this meaning of truth.  They also believe the law of the excluded middle is True (also standard since Plato; made explicit by Aristotle).

Under this system, the claim "Cops are racist" must be either True or False (law of excluded middle).  If True, then every cop, everywhere, who ever existed or will someday exist, is/was racist.  If False, then no cop anywhere has ever been, nor ever will be, racist.  Aristotle would allow for the possibility that some cops are racist and some are not; but he would say that in that case, being or not being racist was an accidental rather than an essential property of cops, and therefore we could know nothing and say nothing about whether cops are racist, since "knowledge" by definition (for rationalist philosophers) refers only to essential properties.

People holding these beliefs use neither quantifiers nor quantities in their arguments, since quantification is, to them, unnecessary.  Any claim can be proved True by finding a single instance, or False by finding a single counter-example.  (They ignore Aristotle's proviso that some attributes are accidental, because they're not as smart as Aristotle.  Anyone as smart as Aristotle wouldn't be an Aristotelian in the 21st century.)  This belief system is ineffective at understanding the world, but effective in politics, since it lets you prove anything you want to from just a single example.

(Post-modern philosophy is nothing but the belief that this is the True definition of "true", combined with the observation that nothing in life ever attains this standard of True or False, applied to "deconstruct" whatever the post-modernist doesn't like.)

(B) A typical scientist, engineer, contemporary empirical philosopher, or free-market economist believes that "true" refers not to the human-language claim X (in words), but to a statistical claim about the frequency with which, or the probability that, some quantitative restatement of "X" holds.

Suppose that X = "Artificial food coloring makes children hyperactive".

A scientist must do something like this to "prove" that X is "true":

1. Specify some repeatable observable phenomenon O.  Here O is a
   time-series comprised of (A) a child eating food with artificial
   colors, and (B) a child's behavior after doing so.
2. Specify some operationalized *measurement* *m* of the *degree to which* X is
   true for a given observable datapoint *o*.  In this case,
   there's a standard operationalized checklist for behaviors
   indicating hyperactivity; a child's hyperactivity score *m* will
   then be how many times they acted out any behavior on the checklist
   within, say, 30 minutes of eating a cookie with 1 gram of some kind
   of food coloring.
3. Propose 2 mutually-exclusionary hypotheses, X and Y, about how every instance
   o is generated.  In this case, hypothesis X is
   "eating 1 gram of this food color increases frequency of hyperactive
   behavior".  Hypothesis Y is "hyperactive behavior is uncorrelated
   with eating 1 gram of this food coloring."
4. Find Q unbiased samples of N instances of such observational data.
   In this case, find N "typical" children, who
   are, in genetics, environmental background, age, weight, sex,
   health, etc., representative of the population to which your claim X
   will be applied.
5. Divide your sample into two groups, G1 (who will eat food coloring)
   and G0 (who won't).  In this case we will actually just test all of
   the children at least twice, getting food coloring half the time,
   and no food coloring half the time.
6. Restate X in terms of your measurement, as X'.  In this case,
   X' = "For every child, average hyperactivity scale score will be higher
   in the half hour after eating a cookie containing 1g of (the specific food coloring)."
7. Run the experiment, and record the hyperactivity scores and compute the mean and variance for group G1 (tests after eating food coloring) and G0 (tests after not eating food coloring).
8. Let n*i* = number of observations in group *i*. Compute the sample mean m*i* and *sample* variance v*i* of the hyperactivity scores of groups G1 and G0: m1, v1, m0, v0.
9. Perform a [T-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test), or an F-test, or some other standard statistical test, at the 95% confidence level.  That means you find the value *t* of a function *T(m1,v1,n1,m0,v0,n0)* such that the probability *P* that {a set of N random observations generated by hypothesis Y would, by chance, have *T(m1,v1,n1,m0,v0,n0)* >= *t*} is 0.95. In the food coloring example, we'd use a [between-groups t-test](http://web.pdx.edu/%7Enewsomj/pa551/lecture6.htm).
10. If *T > t*, we say that, if our samples were unbiased, the claim X' (not X) has been proven with confidence 0.95.  You could say X has a truth of 0.95.  Note that it's theoretically impossible to ever prove something is True, meaning it has a truth of 1.0.
11. If instead P > 0.05, we do NOT say we've disproven X'.  We say that we failed to prove X' at the 95% confidence level.

(The claim X', that hyperactivity score of all children goes up after eating cookies, failed repeatedly to be proven at the 95% confidence level.   Unfortunately, every medical journal article reporting such an experiment incorrectly stated in its conclusion that it had *disproven* the hypothesis that food coloring increases hyperactivity.  As I just explained, that conclusion is not licensed.  Decades later, the claim X, that eating food coloring causes hyperactivity, was proven to be true in children with particular genetics.  The claim that failed to be proven at the 95% confidence level was that food coloring causes hyperactivity in *all* children.  Furthermore, it could still be true that food coloring causes hyperactivity in all children, but by such a small amount that you'd need a much larger sample size to prove it at the 95% confidence level.)

(C) Someone with a better understanding of math and of language would never regard anything stated in a human language as capable of being shown "true" or "false".  Rather, they would take such a statement and try to completely operationalize it in terms of primitive features, ideally down to the level of, say, pixel values in an image.  Then they would compute the predictive value of the discrimination performed by their operationalized claim over a large, typical (not "unbiased") data set.  Those claims which produced the most predictive value (measured in bits of information) per computation (measured in bits of computational entropy) would be retained.  They wouldn't be called "true", but "useful".  This is what deep learning networks do.

Comment: Which is why the quoted passage has an ending, one you apparently did not feel compelled to address.

Comment: Of course you can isolate the meaning of a single word that way. Colloquially acceleration generally means going faster. We hardly ever say the car is accelerating when it's braking. In physics however and even approaching the question philosophically it's still acceleration, just in an opposite direction. It's like saying retreating is advancing in the opposite direction. The point is the question is about the English as it's spoken by ordinary people.

Comment: @Zebrafish Neither you nor Robusto understand my answer. There is no common de dicto "colloquial meaning" used by "ordinary people" for "fact", because there is no common colloquial meaning, even among "ordinary people", to "truth". So you can only give a de re definition of fact, not a single de dicto definition. Look up "de re / de dicto" if you don't know what that means.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how the word "fact" is used in English, that is quite different from what philosophers or mathematicians consider "fact". Here are some more definitions like the one you provided which seemed to prompt you to ask this question:

> c. Something believed to be true or real:
>  [American Heritage
>   Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fact)
>
> 2:a piece of information presented as having objective reality
>   ("presented as having" does not refer to "real" fact - whatever that means)
>   [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fact)

Other definitions are along the lines of:

> "information known to be true".

Would you admit that I can "know" something and be wrong? If that's true, then all other dictionaries allow for "fact" to mean something which is NOT true scientifically/objectively/verifiably.

So if you are interested in how the word "fact" is used in the language itself, forgetting the rigorous definitions of truth and fact that have to do with verification, and leaving apart the special study of epistemology and all the philosophical stuff, it's clear to me that when used in our language "fact" does not always mean something that is true.

Let's say the basis of whether something is fact is a definition, like the IAU's definition of a planet. Pluto is no longer a planet, but a dwarf planet, making the statement "Pluto is not a planet" a fact. Suppose the IAU change the definition tomorrow. Has the fact changed?

Comment: So many people making the same mistakes. It's a fact that the IAU's previous definition of a planet included Pluto. It's a fact that now it doesn't. It's a fact that there now considered to be eight planets in the solar system. These are indisputable statements, which means they are facts. People keep using false statements as if they were facts in order to demonstrate that facts are false. It's maddening.

Answer (score 1):

An etymological note: **fact** comes from a term meaning simply "something done", as [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/fact#etymonline_v_1064) says.

> **fact** (n.)
>
> 1530s, "action, anything done," especially "evil deed," from
> Latin factum "an event, occurrence, deed, achievement," in Medieval
> Latin also "state, condition, circumstance," literally "thing done"
> (source also of Old French fait, Spanish hecho, Italian fatto), noun
> use of neuter of factus, past participle of facere "to do" (from PIE
> root *dhe- "to set, put"). Main modern sense of "thing known to be
> true" is from 1630s, from notion of "something that has actually
> occurred."

A similar phenomenon has occured in Spanish, where two important synonyms for the English "fact" are *hecho* and *dato*, the latter which is immediately related to "datum" in English (see [etymologias.dechile.net](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?fecha)). This, because Latin *facta* is related to when [a letter] was **made**, and *datum* is related to when it was **given**, which, by the way, is another synonym for "fact" in English...

So the sense of a "changeable datum" has departed significantly from it's etymological origin, as indeed many words [have](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy). When once you have *given* something to someone, you cannot change the fact that it *is* given, even if you take it back; but *a piece of information*, once separated from its source, can be changed.

Don't jettison the word, but use it with care.

Etymology aside, here's the word, in the wild:

> And as Felsenthal noted, it is one that will be put to the test.
> “I don’t think there’s ever been a president and vice president to take office in a moment like this, where we don’t just disagree on issues,” he said. “We disagree on basic facts.” ([Washington Post, 10-12-2020](https://www.washingtonpost.com/nation/2020/12/10/time-person-year-biden-harris/))

Comment: A usefull answer to an awkwardly broad question.

Comment: The first part of this answer commits the etymological fallacy. The part about Spanish is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Rosie F: No part of this answer commits the etymological fallacy. It simply states the etymological origin of the word, and the fact that _it meaning has departed_ from its original meaning. The etymologias.dechile entry is related because it is the source explaining the relationship between "fact" and "data".

Comment: related: [alternative facts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369628/what-is-an-alternative-fact)

Comment: I would replace "note" in the first sentence with "fact."

Comment: Some interesting commentary at this question on philosophy.SE [laws are just descriptions of reality](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/106612/if-laws-are-just-descriptions-of-reality-is-it-a-miracle-that-things-are-regula)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm struggling to decide whether to jettison use of the word fact, because the definition appears to be not solid enough to support continued usage.

Very noble. A futile gesture sometimes succeeds. Think of the population of the English speaking word – [20% of 7.8 billion](https://www.babbel.com/en/magazine/how-many-people-speak-english-and-where-is-it-spoken). If a few billion get behind you, you may become part of history.

The beauty of language is that we need not know the precise definition of all the word we speak or write as many of them are subjective and/or contextual.

Definitions do not really exist save in mathematics: the number “four” is understood as being “the sum of two and two. Two has its own definition that is based on the definition of one plus one as expounded by [Whitehead and Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica).

Expecting there be one correct definition for a word is unreasonable - for one or two words would be good. What you need is a ***set*** of words to explain another, plus some examples in context.

What replaces definitions in language are close approximations that more or less capture the essence of a word within a context. I offer you the word “window”: the image in your brain is not the same as mine – my window has no glass, or it could be a window of opportunity.

If I say “**set**” (and nothing else) to you it is meaningless – it has [430 entries in OED](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/english-word-with-the-most-meanings) comprised of 60,000 words and many sub-entries – and you are expecting one true definition of “fact" or, in a fit of pique, you will abandon it, and thus teach the English-speaking world a valuable lesson.

You choose “**fact**” – I would suggest you may think about abandoning “**for**” and a load of other prepositions. The word, “**word**” presents problems in certain contexts – Word!

Answer (score -2):

There are two seemingly contradictory definitions of the word "fact", however there are important distinctions to be made to understand when they're being used.

The first definition states that a fact is a statement that has to be *indisputably* true.

The ever reliable OED confirms this:

> **fact** *n*. a thing that is known to be true

As does the NOAD:

> **fact** |fakt|
> *noun*
> a thing that is indisputably the case

And the Collins COBUILD dictionary:

> **fact**   - A fact is an item of knowledge or information that is true.

However, there is also another definition, meaning something in dispute. This is acknowledged by the OED with an alternative definition:

> A piece of information allegedly or conceivably true; something presented as a fact but which is disputed or unproven

So it is possible to use the word "fact" to mean something believed to be true, however *only if it is not disproven*.

This is an important distinction, and worth repeating: ***If a statement of belief is proven false it is not a "fact".***

Consider Donald Trump's statement that more people attended his inauguration that any other President's in history. He may *believe* it with every fibre of his being, but despite his belief, the statement is disputed by photographic evidence:

[image]

Other times people may be careless with the word "fact". For example, the accepted answer here uses the following example:

> Before 1917, people thought it to be a fact that the atom was the smallest particle of matter. Today, it is a fact that it isn't, and we were wrong in thinking it was...

However before 1917 it would have been careless for someone to write, "it's a fact that the quark is the smallest particle of matter". Typically such statements are written as, "it's a fact that the quark is the smallest *known* particle of matter". The first statement is a belief only (and open to being easily disproven by later science), the second is an indisputable statement of truth: A fact.

Here are some real examples to demonstrate this is how such statements are phrased in the real world:

- [JLab Science - What is the smallest particle of matter *known*?](https://education.jlab.org/qa/quark_01.html)
- [What Is The Smallest Particle We *Know*? - Science ABC](https://www.scienceabc.com/nature/universe/what-is-the-smallest-particle-we-know.html)
- [CERN: The building blocks of matter](https://www.fnal.gov/pub/science/inquiring/matter/index.html) ("Today, physicists don't know of anything smaller than quarks and electrons, but they don't know for sure whether these are the simplest building blocks of matter.")

Anyone saying, "it's a fact that X is the smallest particle of matter", would be making a statement that could easily be disproven in the future, because how can we even be *completely* sure we know the smallest particle of matter? It would be very careless and unscientific to use such language.

Even if they did, it would be a very poor argument because there's no evidence that something smaller doesn't exist.

The accepted answer also uses the following example:

> When a jury convicts a man, it's a fact that he's guilty. If he's later acquitted, it's a fact that he is 'not guilty'.

Again, both statements would likely never be used in reality as it's very possible a case could be overturned. All anyone can say after a court declares a guilty verdict is, "it's a fact that this person was *found* guilty in a court of law".

Even a court of law acknowledges its fallibility, which is why the statement given by the jury when giving their verdict is, "We *find* the defendant guilty" and not "The defendant is guilty".

This continues in all reporting of the trial, too:

- [Harvey Weinstein *found* guilty of rape - BBC News](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-51621041)
- [Fake Heiress Who Swindled N.Y.’s Elite Is *Found* Guilty - The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/25/nyregion/anna-delvey-sorokin-verdict.html)
- [District man *found* not guilty of fatal stabbing - Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/public-safety/district-man-found-not-guilty-in-fatal-stabbing-of-transgender-woman-at-bus-stop/2017/08/16/a1f92436-82ad-11e7-b359-15a3617c767b_story.html)

Whether the person is *actually* "guilty" or "not guilty" remains open to be proven false, and so is not used in real life.

However, again, if someone did, they would be making a statement that would be very hard to backup and claim was a "fact".

It would be akin to stating, "it's a fact that there are no aliens in outer space". Impossible to prove true without venturing into every nook and cranny of the universe, however this statement meets the second definition of "fact".

That all said, if someone found an alien in outer space, then this statement would no longer be considered a fact by *any* definition. Make sense?

Understanding can change over time, too, as mentioned in the accepted answer.

For example, prior to August 2006 it would have been factual to say, "there are nine known planets in the solar system". After Pluto was reclassified as a "dwarf planet", it has since been factually correct to say, "there are eight known planets in the solar system".

Both statements were facts at the time they were made, according to how humans classified planetary bodies when the statements were made. It's *when* the statements were made that defines if they were facts or not.

In the real world, although a "fact" *can* be a belief that hasn't been disproved, it's rare to push that usage when it can be avoided... because it's possible you could shown to be wrong.

People tend to be cautious of making statements which can later be disproven, and the greatest chance of something remaining a fact is to start with the indisputable truth.

In short, if a statement has the potential of being false, as it may not remain a "fact" for very long.

Comment: You're oversimplifying this, I'm afraid. Rightly or wrongly, anything can be called a fact, even if it's not verifiable. Beliefs, opinions, and judgment calls are often confused with facts. Even NOAD seems to be inconsistent with its example: "She lacks political experience" could easily be an erroneous assumption based on perceived stage fright or a bad outing at a debate.

Comment: It bends my brain that an *English language* community has fallen into the trap of debating philosophy. A fact is a true statement. If it's determined to be untrue, then it's no longer a fact (and indeed, never *was* a fact).

Comment: OED, M-W and AHD provide alternative, looser definitions that it is unscholarly to neglect even to mention.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is simply untrue. The definitions you mention pertain only to the legal terms "question of fact" and "finding of fact". Even in a legal sense the word "fact" has the same meaning I ascribe here. I could add countless other dictionaries, but that would be pointlessly excessive. And it's worth pointing out that no other answer has listed every other dictionary, and most don't even have any references. One rule for the answer you disagree with, another rule for those you don't...

Comment: I suggest you read the AHD usage note. // I've commented on other answers here, but yours is the only one that says so forcibly 'Yes, a fact is a statement that has to be indisputably true.' O..'s answer obviously quotes from OED; the answer gainsays what you say here. OED trumps every other dictionary on quality of research and assessment of usage. It must (being larger) contain information that other dictionaries miss.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How am I not already addressing this? Quote: "Some people use the word 'fact' to stress a belief, but they can be corrected if what they believe isn't a fact."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've reworded my answer to include the alternative OED definition and make my statement less forcibly! :) Hopefully it'll earn your upvote.

Comment: No, I still can't agree. " 'When a jury convicts a man, it's a fact that he's guilty' [is an] example of the misuse of the word 'fact'. " That's assuming one definition of 'guilty' (ie etically culpable) whereas 'guilty' in legal terms is a classification of someone on trial reached by say a jury. Hopefully, the two correspond, but sadly this is of course sometimes not the case. // 0 ..'s answer seems fine to me, so adjusting another answer to match it does not merit an upvote.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 1/ I did not adjust my answer to match another. I added the information you flagged as missing. What was the purpose of your comment if not for that? 2/ I've again re-written that section of the answer you flagged. 3/ This answer adds important distinctions and examples which are missing from other answers, including the overly simplistic accepted answer.