# Meaning of the sentence "the body was found murdered by John"

Tags: meaning, commas, ambiguity, relative-clauses

Which of the two versions

*Mr.S. was found murdered, by John*

*Mr.S. was found, murdered by John*

means that John found the body and which one means that John was the murderer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first version has at least three meanings: John found the body; John did the murder;  someone found Mr S murdered and lying at the side of John (we don't know if John was dead too, or merely lying there).

The second simply means that the murdered body was found and that John did the murder.

Comment: A reasonable question of ambiguity, this one has indeed joined a number of questions demoted, evicted, locked, and duplicked — all in the last few days. The moves seemed rash, however deserved. Especially for newbies, how about cutting them some slack? Modeling the behavior we want for ourselves, especially now, we could use the Good Teacher method: "What is 2 + 2?" "22!" "**Yes**, that's the answer to another question! Save it when I ask what is 11 + 11."

Comment: It would seem silly to lock a post, for problems with its content, without explaining to the author what the problem is.

Comment: @HotLicks, it's a comment lock.  Most likely, it was attracting answers in the comments.

Comment: I agree with the sentiments expressed here. There is no such thing as a stupid question, only stupid answers. We should be tolerant and welcoming or, at least, explain any negativity.

Comment: This OP has a complicated past. I was trying to clarify the intent of the question  with comments...I do not see how locking the Q contributes to the clarification. @Mark

Comment: IOW...if we cannot advise the OP about issues with its content, how do we improve it? In the comment sections of an answer like this one? This is  pretzel logic...and counter-productive.

Comment: Now that is a neat (and appropriate) phrase, new to me, *pretzel logic*.. Love it. I am going to use that occasionally.

Comment: @Anton I guess you missed [this post...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/548537/figure-eight-logic-meaning/548554#548554)

Comment: @Cascabel Indeed I did but I am grateful to you for quoting from it. It's a gem.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Hot Licks, and Anton...see [my recent post on meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14852/whats-up-with-locking-new-questions)  concerning this issue.